Piano voice guitar sheet music
Got a chord in music b c e b with square shaped bracket next to it. I tried playing it but finger can’t stretch to other b octave higher. It is on a P V G sheet music from Sound of Music.

The square bracket means to play both the B and C with your thumb. See What is the best way to play a chord larger than your hand?.

Thanks very much
